# Probability of Overlapping Interval

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Suppose I have two "lanes" where each lane is made of infinite number of segments of the same length.

Example 1:

```
|----  --||--  ----||----  --||--- ...
|----||--  --||----||----||--  --|| ...
```

1st lane: segments of length 6. 2nd lane: segments of length 4.

Example 2:

```
|----  ----||----  ----||---- ...
|----||----||----||----||----|| ...
```

1st lane: segments of length 8. 2nd lane: segments of length 4

For a segment in a particular lane, how can I calculate the expected number of segments that cover it on the other side? Along with the distribution?

In example 2, the 2nd lane is always covered by the segment of the 1st lane. Hence the expected number of segments that cover it should be one, along with the distribution. Meanwhile, the 1st lane is always covered by two segments of the 2nd lane. Hence, the expected value should be two, and the distribution is (1/2, 1/2).

In example 1, the coverage distribution for the 1st lane is always either (1/3, 2/3) or (2/3, 1/3). Meanwhile, for the 2nd lane, the coverage distribution is always either (1) or (1/2, 1/2).
Is there any particular probability formula that can be referred to for calculating the expected distribution of such a case?

Comment: You don't supply any information relevant to probability calculations, which makes your question unanswerable.  What exactly is supposed to vary randomly in this setup??